# Remove pagebreak fields in Drupal Webform submission email

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I currently have the following as an output in my email, and wish to remove the pagebreaks from the email that gets sent.

Any idea what I need to put in webform-mail.tpl.php?

```
Application form completed on Wednesday, February 2, 2011 - 14:17 by 69.10.172.83

--Next--
--Next--
--Next--
--Next--
--Next--
Total: £0

Your personal reference number is: WSE93
```

**EDIT**

I have tried Ayush's solution in my theme template.php, plus webform-mail.tpl.php and webform.module to no success. ANyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function hook_webform_submission_render_alter(&$renderable) {
  // Remove page breaks from sent e-mails.
  if (isset($renderable['#email'])) {
    foreach (element_children($renderable) as $key) {
      if ($renderable[$key]['#component']['type'] == 'pagebreak') {
        unset($renderable[$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

see [this](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_webform_submission_render_alter/7)

Comment: Hi ayush, thankyou - I have tried this in my webform-mail.tpl.php already with no luck.

Comment: Is it possible to put this in my theme template.php file or stick it in webform.module?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to put that in a custom module, like `mymodule.module` with the name 
`mymodule_webform_submission_render_alter(&$renderable)` to make it work.